# Factor variables may not contain noninteger values

Tags: regression, stata

I am attempting to fit a regression model in Stata. My variables are are all continuous variables of type float.

```
regress _gdp all_indexn_c 90_days consistent _incpc all_indexn_c#90_days

all_indexn_c:  factor variables may not contain noninteger values
r(452);
```

[image]

How do I fix this issue? I don't have factor variables and I'd like to use float variables in the model.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1629180-factor-variables-may-not-contain-noninteger-values It's always courteous to tell people about cross-posting.

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises because you're asking for an interaction term and if you do that Stata requires you to flag that a variable with non-integer values is continuous. See for example `help fvvarlist`.

Running this reproducible example shows a similar problem and its fix.

```
sysuse auto, clear
regress price mpg headroom mpg#headroom
regress price mpg headroom mpg#c.headroom
```

P.S. Regressions with GDP pc as outcome usually work better on a logarithmic scale.